# view controller in reverse direction on Device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, viewcontroller

i have a project with navigation bar it  open correctly on iPhone simulator and the back button appear on the left correctly and all the transition is normal from left to right
but on device the navigation became reversed and the back button became on the right instead on the left

Comment: Which language is the device running on?

Comment: try changing device dude :) I never had such issue, I believe if your code is working on simulator and not working on device must be some settings/issue with device

Comment: its arabic lang and ios9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the feature of device because the language which you selected has also the reverse direction than the English language.

If you set this language in iPhone simulator than you will get the same behaviour as device.

Reference link :
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Comment: thank you  i add this  if(([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] respondsToSelector:@selector(isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:)]) && [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:(NSOperatingSystemVersion){9, 0, 0}]){
    [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];}